# I don't think it's getting all the info from other files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pygame, tile

I'm working on a pygame project but when I run it, it's not working.
There are a lot of messages in my code saying the files imported may be "undefined or defined" which is confusing. I can't tell if that's the reason or not.
(I'm using repl.it, and just started trying to learn pygame a week ago)

main.py CODE:

```
from settings import *
from tiles import tiles
#pygame setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
test_tile = pygame.sprite.Group(Tile(100, 100), 200)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

screen.fill('black')
test.tile.draw(screen)

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

settings.py CODE:

```
  '                              ',
  '                              ',
  '                              ',
  ' XX    XXX              XX    ',
  ' XX                           ',
  ' XXXX          XX          XX ',
  ' XXXX        XX               ',
  ' XX    X   XXXX    XX    XX   ',
  '       X   XXXX    XX    XXX  ',
  '    XXXX   XXXXXX  XX    XXXX ',
  'XXXXXXXX   XXXXXX  XX    XXXX ',]

tile_size = 64
screen_width = 1200
screen_height = len(level_map) * tile_size
```

tiles.py CODE:

```
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self,pos,size):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
    self.image.fill('grey')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

Comment: You really need to include all error messages into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is almost there.  For the moment I suggest simply putting everything in a single file.  Obviously in the long-term this gets messy, but for now it will be easier.

There's a couple of bugs around the [Sprite Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) creation, and adding the [Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) to it.

The code needs to first create a Sprite Group, *then* add Sprites to it.  It's possible to create the tiles as they're added to the group, all in single line of code, but this will be unworkable later.

```
map_tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()            # Sprite Group
test_tile = Tile( (100, 100), TILE_SIZE )    # Sprite

map_tiles.add( test_tile )                   # Put Sprite into Sprite Group
```

With that change, and a few tweaks, it's working:

```
import pygame

### Settings
level_map = [ 
  '                              ',
  '                              ',
  '                              ',
  ' XX    XXX              XX    ',
  ' XX                           ',
  ' XXXX          XX          XX ',
  ' XXXX        XX               ',
  ' XX    X   XXXX    XX    XX   ',
  '       X   XXXX    XX    XXX  ',
  '    XXXX   XXXXXX  XX    XXXX ',
  'XXXXXXXX   XXXXXX  XX    XXXX ',]

GREY  = ( 128, 128, 128 )
BLACK = (   0,   0,   0 )

TILE_SIZE = 64
SCREEN_WIDTH  = len( level_map[0] ) * TILE_SIZE
SCREEN_HEIGHT = len( level_map ) * TILE_SIZE


### Tile Sprite class
class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self,pos,size):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    self.image.fill( GREY )
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)


#pygame setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
map_tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()           # Group of all map tiles
test_tile = Tile( (100, 100), TILE_SIZE )   # A single map Tile

map_tiles.add( test_tile )                  # Put tile-sprite into group


#main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # paint the screen
    screen.fill( BLACK )
    map_tiles.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()

    # clamp refresh-rate to 60 FPS
    clock.tick(60)

# exiting    
pygame.quit()
#sys.exit()
```

Typically all constants, for example "tile-size" are written in all-capitals.  This allows the person reading the code to immediately know what it represents when reading it.